# Luks2 does not accept unlock password after fixing efi boot

Tags: linux, luks, external-hdd, dm-crypt

I have 2 usb's of different brands and capacities encrypted with Luks2 using Kali's disk tool. After correcting a problem with the boot and correcting the path I was able to access the disks, but afterwards, they simply do not accept the password.
I performed a test with another disk and it works normally.
Would some change in the sectors be the cause?!

```
WD-1TB-LUKS2: /dev/sdd (/dev/sdd1)

LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          3
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
UUID:           afa33689-994f-4bfb-b68a-95166bedab82
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          (no flags)

Data segments:
  0: crypt
        offset: 16777216 [bytes]
        length: (whole device)
        cipher: aes-xts-plain64
        sector: 512 [bytes]

Keyslots:
  0: luks2
        Key:        512 bits
        Priority:   normal
        Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
        Cipher key: 512 bits
        PBKDF:      argon2id
        Time cost:  11
        Memory:     1048576
        Threads:    4
        Salt:       96 09 fc 6e aa 98 0c 72 26 2f ba ec cb e0 c7 e8 
                    ac a5 eb 85 b7 6b a9 e0 b6 3c e0 04 a8 76 f7 3c 
        AF stripes: 4000
        AF hash:    sha256
        Area offset:32768 [bytes]
        Area length:258048 [bytes]
        Digest ID:  0
Tokens:
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
        Hash:       sha256
        Iterations: 319298
        Salt:       4e a7 01 b3 da 77 af 03 a6 e1 2f ea a4 aa 89 92 
                    bd c2 bc bc 92 32 63 6c eb fc 80 58 02 42 94 4b 
        Digest:     f7 4c 33 2b 1b 23 de 36 36 2d d5 e8 57 8d 6e 09 
                    fa 0b 50 88 ed e3 9a d6 76 5f 90 42 e4 48 ea 10
```

Second Disk

```
HDD-LUKS2-500GB
LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          3
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
UUID:           20f8e19c-a37d-4049-91d4-571e14a02efa
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          (no flags)

Data segments:
  0: crypt
        offset: 16777216 [bytes]
        length: (whole device)
        cipher: aes-xts-plain64
        sector: 512 [bytes]

Keyslots:
  0: luks2
        Key:        512 bits
        Priority:   normal
        Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
        Cipher key: 512 bits
        PBKDF:      argon2id
        Time cost:  7
        Memory:     1048576
        Threads:    4
        Salt:       9f 98 26 e8 5f 2d d2 78 f8 ac 87 d1 a9 40 05 56 
                    d7 4b b3 35 e0 2f 84 bf 7e 48 5b 69 14 ff 1a db 
        AF stripes: 4000
        AF hash:    sha256
        Area offset:32768 [bytes]
        Area length:258048 [bytes]
        Digest ID:  0
Tokens:
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
        Hash:       sha256
        Iterations: 320861
        Salt:       13 4c f8 91 c9 25 cb b9 ef b4 2b 25 36 a8 d7 d8 
                    90 c1 36 0e 2c cf 51 04 b1 3c e1 54 04 1c 42 35 
        Digest:     d8 a0 c5 d8 7b 09 a9 a3 d4 07 af 09 da 41 2e e3 
                    6e c5 d2 e0 33 95 fc 12 d0 21 98 58 5c 5a 12 0b
```

Only working disk with Luks2 :

```
HDD-32GB0-WD    

LUKS header information
Version:        2
Epoch:          3
Metadata area:  16384 [bytes]
Keyslots area:  16744448 [bytes]
UUID:           5948fcd5-e99d-4c53-991b-459b60cce38f
Label:          (no label)
Subsystem:      (no subsystem)
Flags:          (no flags)

Data segments:
  0: crypt
        offset: 16777216 [bytes]
        length: (whole device)
        cipher: aes-xts-plain64
        sector: 4096 [bytes]

Keyslots:
  0: luks2
        Key:        512 bits
        Priority:   normal
        Cipher:     aes-xts-plain64
        Cipher key: 512 bits
        PBKDF:      argon2id
        Time cost:  10
        Memory:     1048576
        Threads:    4
        Salt:       ed ad 79 93 45 58 0f 41 93 75 1f 1b a5 85 48 43 
                    3b db 27 73 95 ed de 6c 79 46 48 12 c7 60 96 48 
        AF stripes: 4000
        AF hash:    sha256
        Area offset:32768 [bytes]
        Area length:258048 [bytes]
        Digest ID:  0
Tokens:
Digests:
  0: pbkdf2
        Hash:       sha256
        Iterations: 302706
        Salt:       62 80 da cb 32 b6 1d 71 3c 36 e3 7c 91 35 2c 4b 
                    a1 34 25 27 33 a1 dc 24 bf b4 f7 47 08 d2 20 3c 
        Digest:     e0 e1 03 bb 4a 04 5e 93 32 5d 91 c2 b3 db 01 f1 
                    ee 48 f5 76 70 c9 63 33 65 40 19 fb d3 71 68 55
```

Disk info...

```
Crypttab output
$cat /etc/crypttab   
# <target name> <source device>         <key file>      <options>

$sudo blkid -t TYPE=crypto_LUKS -o device                                                                                                                                                                                           2 ⨯
/dev/sdd1
/dev/sdc1

lsblk output

sdc                   8:32   0 465,8G  0 disk 
└─sdc1                8:33   0 465,8G  0 part 
sdd                   8:48   0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sdd1                8:49   0 931,5G  0 part

More info and test :

$sudo fdisk -l                              
Disk /dev/sdc: 465,76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Touro Mobile 3.0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5dc1c757

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 976773119 976771072 465,8G e8 unknown


Disk /dev/sdd: 931,51 GiB, 1000204885504 bytes, 1953525167 sectors
Disk model: Expansion       
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1c5a16fb

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 1953523711 1953521664 931,5G e8 unknown
                                

$ sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdc1                                                                                                                                                                                                
500106788864                                
                 
$ sudo blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdd1   
1000203091968                 
                 
                 
sudo parted /dev/sdc unit s print free
Model: HGST Touro Mobile 3.0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 976773168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start       End         Size        Type     File system  Flags
        2s          2047s       2046s                Free Space
 1      2048s       976773119s  976771072s  primary
        976773120s  976773167s  48s                  Free Space

        
        
$ sudo parted /dev/sdd unit s print free
Model: Seagate Expansion (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 1953525167s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start        End          Size         Type     File system  Flags
        2s           2047s        2046s                 Free Space
 1      2048s        1953523711s  1953521664s  primary
        1953523712s  1953525166s  1455s                 Free Space
        
        
        
sudo cryptsetup --debug --verbose luksOpen /dev/sdc1 Device  
[sudo] senha para rocket: 
# cryptsetup 2.5.0 processing "cryptsetup --debug --verbose luksOpen /dev/sdc1 Device"
# Verifying parameters for command open.
# Running command open.
# Locking memory.
# Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
# Unblocking interruption on signal.
# Allocating context for crypt device /dev/sdc1.
# Trying to open and read device /dev/sdc1 with direct-io.
# Initialising device-mapper backend library.
# Trying to load any crypt type from device /dev/sdc1.
# Crypto backend (OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022 [default][legacy]) initialized in cryptsetup library version 2.5.0.
# Detected kernel Linux 5.16.0-kali3-amd64 x86_64.
# Loading LUKS2 header (repair disabled).
# Acquiring read lock for device /dev/sdc1.
# Opening lock resource file /run/cryptsetup/L_8:33
# Verifying lock handle for /dev/sdc1.
# Device /dev/sdc1 READ lock taken.
# Trying to read primary LUKS2 header at offset 0x0.
# Opening locked device /dev/sdc1
# Verifying locked device handle (bdev)
# LUKS2 header version 2 of size 16384 bytes, checksum sha256.
# Checksum:684ff912851560ae94bd6d4af4ec447040f62dae3f7596e2aed9f7a05fe74e82 (on-disk)
# Checksum:684ff912851560ae94bd6d4af4ec447040f62dae3f7596e2aed9f7a05fe74e82 (in-memory)
# Trying to read secondary LUKS2 header at offset 0x4000.
# Reusing open ro fd on device /dev/sdc1
# LUKS2 header version 2 of size 16384 bytes, checksum sha256.
# Checksum:00a1dd76822bd4f47afda8191840b95a1d2f8448419f4f7d89ade082bbd08e31 (on-disk)
# Checksum:00a1dd76822bd4f47afda8191840b95a1d2f8448419f4f7d89ade082bbd08e31 (in-memory)
# Device size 500106788864, offset 16777216.
# Device /dev/sdc1 READ lock released.
# PBKDF argon2id, time_ms 2000 (iterations 0), max_memory_kb 1048576, parallel_threads 4.
# Activating volume Device using token (any type) -1.
# dm version   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
# dm versions   [ opencount flush ]   [16384] (*1)
# Detected dm-ioctl version 4.45.0.
# Device-mapper backend running with UDEV support enabled.
# dm status Device  [ opencount noflush ]   [16384] (*1)
No usable token is available.
# Interactive passphrase entry requested
```

Return incorrect password.

Use this informations and others,
Read information -> https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248553
https://superuser.com/questions/1740773/unsure-if-i-encrypted-external-hdd-correctly-with-luks
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=280531 and others...

Comment: LUKS2 has redundant header (secondary header mentioned in your debug output) but no redundant key material, so if you somehow damaged your key material, it's game over. Check keyslot Area offset+length with hexdump, if should look like random data. `hexdump -C --skip=32768 --length=258048 /dev/sdc1 | less`

Comment: It would be something like:
00041160  be 9d a7 d6 82 98 8a cd  94 dd ec 9c 81 df ed 97  |................| 

?

Comment: Yeah... the key material has to be random data as a whole. If it isn't then it's certainly bad. There is no other way to really verify it - the checksum only covers the metadata, not key material. So if your passphrase is not accepted - it's one of wrong pass, wrong keyboard layout, bad keyfile (newline issues when reading from stdin), corrupt key material, bad ram, etc...

Comment: The password is correct, I've been using it for 10 years and it would be very difficult to forget, although not impossible. This occurred after accessing this disk, shortly after correcting the path, and shortly after I used this disk and in sequence the second one that also appears problems.
However, knowing that it is something unavoidable, I will unfortunately redo it. Sad to lose years of work and actions. But thanks for your help my friend.

Comment: In wd 1TB i found this:
00037fe0  b4 2e d4 a7 aa 8f e2 9f  1f bf 15 03 af 8f d5 8a  |................|

Comment: You can also try it from a livecd, just to rule out any problems with your local install or software... you can also type your passphrase in a text editor, maybe there's a dead key on your keyboard for a key you don't usually use or notice? Not sure what else to suggest. It's not supposed to happen - but it is also why backups are so important

Comment: I actually already performed the test on a fresh install of Debian, because I recently performed a BIOS update on the MSI B550 and installed an RX6600. The password was typed several times in a text file, including, there was a mousepad document that I discarded, which was the recovery of a temporary CTRL + C and CTRL + V that I used to not have to type. But when restarting the machine I discarded it and I can't recover it to perform the comparison. The keyboard, layout, are OK. I tested it on an HP machine with linux and I wasn't successful either.